# is there any simliar function of idxmax() in py-polars in groupby?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd


A = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b']
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]


df = pl.DataFrame({'cola':A,
                   'colb':B})


df_pd = df.to_pandas()

index = df_pd.groupby('cola')['colb'].idxmax()
df_pd.loc[index,'top'] = 1
```

in pandas i can get the column of top using idxmax().

however, in polars

i use the arg_max()

```
index = df[pl.col('colb').arg_max().over('cola').flatten()]
```

seems  cannot get what i want..

is there any way to get generate a column of 'top' in polars?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polars, window functions (the `.over()`) will do an aggregation + self-join (see https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.over.html?highlight=over#polars.Expr.over), which means you cannot return a unique value per row, which is what you are after.

A way to compute the top column is to use `apply`:

```py
df.groupby("cola").apply(lambda x: x.with_columns([pl.col("colb"), (pl.col("colb")==pl.col("colb").max()).alias("top")]))
```

Comment: thx a lot! dude!

Comment: This works but uses `apply`, which doesn't use the Expressions API and so should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` and `over`:

```py
df.with_columns(top=(pl.col('colb') == pl.col('colb').max()).over('cola'))
```

This gives you

```py
shape: (14, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ cola ┆ colb ┆ top   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 2    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 3    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 4    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 5    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 6    ┆ false │
│ a    ┆ 7    ┆ true  │
│ b    ┆ 8    ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 9    ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 10   ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 11   ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 12   ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 13   ┆ false │
│ b    ┆ 14   ┆ true  │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

You can then cast to `pl.Int64` if you want `1`s and `0`s

Comment: I appreciate you helping out readers, but it would be fair to acknowledge that the currently accepted solution was at the time the only way to achieve this (`over` behaviour has changed). I.e., this solution was not working two years ago.